# cannot open load file: /yasnippet

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I receive this message every time I start emacs

```
Emacs 24.2
Win7 64 and Ubuntu 12.10
yasnippet 0.8.0 installed with package-list
```

If there is a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 6):

yasnippet doesn't get initialised automatically when installed with elpa, which I find unconventional. You still need to add the yasnippet directory into your load-path.

Here is my set up in my .emacs

```
;; yasnippet
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0")
(require 'yasnippet)
(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0/snippets" "~/Dropbox/Applications/Customise/emacs/myyassnipets"))
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of message I would expect to see if you're calling `load` or `load-file` in your init.el with a bad path. Look for any uses of those functions and correct the path if you can.

If this is in code you control, you probably want to call `(require 'yasnippet)` instead of directly loading the file.